# Finite dimensional normed space

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

What is the largest possible $c$ in the equation shown in the following image for if $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $x_1 = (1, 0),x_2 = (0, 1)?$ If $X = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $x_1 = (1, 0, 0), x_2 = (0, 1,0), x_3 = (0, 0, 1)$

$$||\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2+\cdots+\alpha_n x_n||\geq c(|\alpha_1|+|\alpha_2|+\cdots+|\alpha_n|)$$

I tried to solve with myself but I couldn't. How can I proceed in that question?

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. Please remove the link and write the equation as part of your question.

Comment: what is $||.||$?

Comment: ||.||: It defines the norm.

Comment: I know it, but which norm, $p-$norm for example?

Comment: @RaziehNoori since he doesn't seem to know what a $p$-norm is, $p=2$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, noting that

$$
|\alpha_1| + \cdots + |\alpha_n|  = 
(|\alpha_1|, \dots, |\alpha_n|) \cdot (1,\dots,1) \leq \cdots ?
$$

Comment: .@Omnomnomnom sir  can u elaborate more ?

Comment: @jasmine The Cauchy Schwarz inequality says that $|v \cdot w| = \|v\| \cdot \|w\|$ holds for any vectors $v,w \in \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: It says that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a valid $c$, how do we assure that it is the greatest?

Comment: @JohnMars By finding a non-zero vector for which the two sides are equal, i.e. showing that the inequality is “tight”.